# What is the purpose of count method of range class?

Tags: python, count, range

I found that `range` class defines a method named `count` that returns the number of occurrences of value.

I think this should be replaced by a method `exists` returning `True` or `False` in case the value is or is not in the objet.
In fact, the number returned by `count` method is either `O` or `1`, it cannot be greater in my opinion.

Comment: That method already exists too – it’s the `in` operator. `5 in range(3, 10, 2)`

Comment: To see if a value is in a range, use `if some_value in range(start, end, step):`, not `count()`. `count` is probably implemented since it is a Sequence, and that method is one of those defined in that abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` is a method of [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)s. `range` implements `count` so that it can properly be considered a `Sequence`, and efficiently implement it as it sees fit; even if it isn't the most useful operation on that exact type.

It also implements `__contains__`, and I wouldn't be surprised if `count` is implemented in terms of `__contains__`.

Answer (score 1):

`exists` is already implemented as the `in` operator; you're welcome to use that for your desired application.

`count` is implemented because `range` is a `Sequence`, as are `list`, `tuple`, and `str`.  Thus, `count` must exist and be consistent with its functionality in the other `Sequence` types.